# Why is this array value getting deleted but still prints?

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, queue

This script is a very simplyfied version of a bigger one I have, the thing I do here is to delete "pip" if theres an array value like that. But the problem comes when the second cycle comes (or even with more), pip continues printing in the screen and I dont want to do that.

```
import requests, threading, random, string, json, time, queue, re

num_worker_threads = int(input("Threads: "))

lista = ['asd', 'asdjk', 'pip', 'lasd', 'lol']
print(str(lista))

def do_work(i):
    try:
        print(i.strip())
        print(str(lista))
        if i == "pip":
            lista.remove("pip")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is not None:
            do_work(item)
            q.task_done()


q = queue.Queue()

threads = []

for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for i in range(2): # I have only put 2 cycles
    for line in lista:
        q.put(line)


q.join()

for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    q.put(None)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some solid concurrency control in your multi threaded code, you need to make sure of a a few things happening in order:

- You want to make sure that the Queue does not read the list again till the thread cleared `pip` from it from first round inserted in the queue.
- You need to make sure that threads are not mutating the same elements at the same time, which will cause one of them to throw exception that it cannot delete a deleted element.

You could make use of `Event` to put some control on the flow of the multi threaded program, let's declare an event called `first_iteration_processsed`, the Queue will wait for this event to be satisfied so that it starts its second iteration of enquening all elements of the list.
The event will be set by one of your threads once it successfully deletes pip from the list.

code sample:

```
import requests, threading, random, string, json, time, queue, re
from threading import Event
num_worker_threads = int(input("Threads: "))

lista = ['asd', 'asdjk', 'pip', 'lasd', 'lol']
print(str(lista))

iteration_processsed = Event()

iteration_processsed.set()
def do_work(i):
    # global lista
    try:
        print(i.strip())
        print(str(lista))
        if i == "pip":
            lista.remove("pip")
            print("Removed pip successfully")
        if i == "iter_end":
            iteration_processsed.set()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is not None:
            do_work(item)
            q.task_done()


q = queue.Queue()

threads = []

for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for i in range(3): # I have only put 2 cycles
    iteration_processsed.wait()
    print(f"Iteration {i} started")
    iteration_processsed.clear()

    for line in lista:
        q.put(line)
    q.put('iter_end')

q.join()

for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    q.put(None)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Let's try this out:

```
Threads: 2
['asd', 'asdjk', 'pip', 'lasd', 'lol']
Iteration 0 started
asd
['asd', 'asdjk', 'pip', 'lasd', 'lol']
asdjk
['asd', 'asdjk', 'pip', 'lasd', 'lol']
pip
['asd', 'asdjk', 'pip', 'lasd', 'lol']
Removed pip successfully
lasd
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
lol
iter_end
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
Iteration 1 started
asd
asdjk
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
lasd
lol
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
iter_end
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
Iteration 2 started
asd
asdjk
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
lasd
lol
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
iter_end
['asd', 'asdjk', 'lasd', 'lol']
```

Now as you can see the second iteration will never start before pip is removed, ofcourse the implement ion here is very much specific to this case, but I guess you could tweak it to your own more general purposes and maybe add more events to lock more operations to be executed in some predefined order.
You could read more about events from the docs or this article is a good start too
https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Event_Objects_between_Threads.php

Comment: Thanks for your response Kareem, I would like to ask: What if I want it to make it a permanent loop so instead of: "for i in range(2):" its a "while True:"?

Comment: sure, check my updated answer. You will need to make the event lock ```iteration_proccessed``` to be used in all subsequent iterations.

Comment: Works, but if there's no "pip" in the 2nd iteration it will give error. Try to do it with 5 cycles using the same code.

Comment: then your thread needs to know more specific info about what an iteration means, maybe place a known keyword like ```q.put('iter_end')``` after finishing each iteration of filing the queue, so that if any of your threads reached that known keyword, he releases the lock instead of releasing it on deleting ```pip```

Comment: Could you explain how can I make it so it can cycle infinite times? it may be one iteration where it deletes "pip", it may be that it doesn't delete any item or maybe another random one.

Comment: check my updated code sample, I tested it with 100 iterations, ofcourse you could replace that with ```while(true)```, but I'm sure you need some stopping condition but it will work for any number of iterations

Comment: I changed the code so that the event lock does not depend on deletion but depends on the end of the iteration and the start of a new one, so I placed a special keyword in Queue for threads to know that they successfully finished an iteration and they could release the lock

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a race condition. The race is between:

- The main thread, which is going to try to add `"pip"` to the queue twice, once on each of its iterations over `lista`.
- The worker threads, which are collectively fetching the items off the queue and processing them. If they process a `"pip"` entry, they'll remove it from `lista`.

If the first `"pip"` entry gets processed by a worker thread and removed from `lista` before the second `"pip"` has been iterated to and added, then it won't be processed again. From your description of the issue though, I'm guessing that thanks to some combination of the GIL and the timing of the different parts of the code, you pretty consistently get both copies of `"pip"` added to the queue before the workers can do anything about it. But that's not strictly guaranteed. If you added a delay in between the iterations of `lista` in the main thread, it would probably give the worker threads time to catch up and remove `"pip"` as you expect:

```
for i in range(2):
    for line in lista:
        q.put(line)
    time.sleep(1) # delay for a second
```

Obviously, that's probably not what you really want to do, as it's still a race, just one that is *likely* to be won by the other racers now (there's no guarantee that the other threads won't take excessively long as well). A better solution would be to design the code so that there is no race condition at all.

One idea might be to `join` the queue in between iterations of the list, so that all the values get processed by the workers before you go to re-add them again. This is pretty similar to the `time.sleep` approach, but it's more reliable, as the main thread will wait for as long as it takes the workers to process the items in the queue before adding any more.

Another idea might be to do the filtering of `"pip"` entries in the main thread, before the values are put into the queue. Just an `if line != "pip"` check might do it!

Comment: The problem is that I have done it like this for simplifying the big script I have, but "pip" could change for another value in any other moment, so I need to reload the array every cycle.